# manually validate my form

Tags: jquery, validation, field

In my jquery script i have two function to validate each and every field in my form. When i click on submit it checks for the validation of each and every field in my form but i want it as to make few of my fields optional.

here is my code

```
function validateSteps(){

    var FormErrors = false;
    for(var i = 1; i < fieldsetCount; ++i){
        var error = validateStep(i);
        if(error == -1){

            FormErrors = true;

        }

        }

    $('#formElem').data('errors',FormErrors);   
}
    function validateStep(step){
    if(step == fieldsetCount) return;

    var error = 1;
    var hasError = false;
    $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')').find(':input:not(button)').each(function(){
        var $this       = $(this);
        var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;

        if(valueLength == ''){

            hasError = true;
            $this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF');
        }
        else
            $this.css('background-color','#FFFFFF');    
    });
    var $link = $('#navigation li:nth-child(' + parseInt(step) + ') a');
    $link.parent().find('.error,.checked').remove();

    var valclass = 'checked';
    if(hasError){

        error = -1;
        valclass = 'error';
    }
    $('<span class="'+valclass+'"></span>').insertAfter($link);

    return error;
}
```

How can i make few of my fields optional ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could narrow down your main selection by doing something like

```
$('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')')
              .find(':input:not(button):not(.nocheck)')
```

Where the class `nocheck` needs to be assigned to those fields you do not want to check (=optional fields).

**Edit:**
The following JSfiddle shows the selection (only) in action: http://jsfiddle.net/K6zpD/
(Open your JavaScript console to look at output. The names of the checked input fields will be listed there.)